# Where is microsoft/dotnet:nanoserver on docker hub

Tags: docker, .net-core

I am new to docker and doing some tutorial courses.
I have just successfully pulled microsoft/dotnet:nanoserver, but I am not clear from where the docker has got this image.

Upon searching I came to [Ms page on docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/u/microsoft/) where I found the dotnet core repo.

[image: microsoft docker hub page]

Here it reads "Official images for .NET Core and ASP.NET Core for Linux and **Windows Nano Server**"

And when I visit [ms dotnet on docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core), things are still not clear about a few things.

First, where is the docker pull command? If I visit [Windows Server Core portal](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore), you can find a link like below. See the picture below where I show the link. But now, where is such a link when I visit https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore
```

Second, where is information about nano server. Note the first picture above talks about windows nano server.

Am I missing something very trivial? This is quite confusing, please help.

[image: Window Server Core portal on Docker hub]

Answer (score 1):

## Edited Answer:

Docker has a feature called multi-arch image repository.
Under which a repository can contain platform variants.
Based on your arch/OS setting docker will pull the correct image.
So `dotnet/core` will pull buster-slim on Linux and Windows Nano Server on windows docker installation.

## Original Answer:

Looks like the pull commands are wrong.
I switched Arch/OS to the Windows/AMD64

I was successfully able to pull the `dotnet:nanoserver image`

command: `docker run -it microsoft/dotnet:nanoserver`

And it'll launch a command prompt C:\

I don't know why it is running dotnet 1.1.11

[image]